# Python, Flask и AJAX - отправка формы

Tags: javascript, html, python, flask

Пишу на Python 2.7, использую Flask в виде web сервера.

1. В Python есть скрипт/скрипты:

   ```
   @app.route('/enc_config', methods=['POST', 'GET']) 
   def enc_config():
   config.read('config.ini')
   if request.method == 'GET':
       d = collections.OrderedDict()
       d['status'] = 200
       d['width'] = config.getint('ENCODER', 'width')
       d['heigth'] = config.getint('ENCODER', 'heigth')
       d['record_dir'] = config.get('ENCODER', 'record_dir')
       d['record_file'] = config.get('ENCODER', 'record_file')
       d['video_format'] = config.get('ENCODER', 'video_fmt')
       d['image_dir'] = config.get('ENCODER', 'img_dir')
       d['image_file'] = config.get('ENCODER' , 'img_file')
       d['image_format'] = config.get('ENCODER', 'img_fmt')
       d['image_effect'] = config.get('ENCODER' , 'image_effect')
       return flask_json.dumps(d, sort_keys=False, indent=True)
   else :
       # Not finished - need to write all changes in config.ini
       _width = request.form['_width']
       _heigth = request.form['_heigth']
       _video_fmt = request.form['_video_fmt']
       _image_fmt = request.form['_image_fmt']
       config.set('ENCODER', 'width', '%s' % _width)
       config.set('ENCODER', 'heigth', '%s' % _heigth)
       config.set('ENCODER', 'video_fmt', '%s' % _video_fmt)
       config.set('ENCODER', 'image_fmt', '%s' % _image_fmt)
       config.write(open('config.ini', 'w'))
       d = collections.OrderedDict()
       d['status'] = 200
       d['width'] = config.getint('ENCODER', 'width')
       d['heigth'] = config.getint('ENCODER', 'heigth')
       d['record_dir'] = config.get('ENCODER', 'record_dir')
   return flask_json.dumps(d, sort_keys=False, indent=True)
   ```

   В нем есть два метода запроса, `GET` и `POST`, если запрос `GET` - получаем ответ в `json` формате из данных которые записаны в `config.ini`.
   Если запрос `POST`, должны отправится данные из формы в `html` и пере-записаться в `config.ini` .

   2. HTML и JS

```js
$(".control").find("button").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var url = $this.attr("formaction");
    var post = $this.attr("post");
    $this.click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            processData: true,
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            data: post,
            success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
    console.log(data);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

```css
body {
    background: url(images/background.gif) no-repeat;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lato/v7/qIIYRU-oROkIk8vfvxw6QvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff) format('woff');
}

.wrap {
    width:250px;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
.rpi-logo {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 65px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 65px;
    background: #a50e39 ;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -15px;
}
.rpi-logo img {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    border:3px solid #fff;
    display: block;
}
.wrap input {
    border: none;
    background: #fff;
    font-family:Lato ;
    font-weight:700 ;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    width: calc(100% - 24px) ;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
}
.bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #fff ;
}
.bar i {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 1px ;
    display: block;
    background: #d1d1d1;
}
.wrap input[type="text"] {
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px ;
}
.wrap input[type="password"] {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px ;
}
.forgot_link {
    color: #83afdf ;
    color: #83afdf;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    position: relative;
    left: 193px;
    top: -36px;
}
.wrap button {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: #a50e39;
    text-decoration: center;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top:-5px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<div>INDEX.HTML</div>
{% if error %}
    <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}{% endif %}

<form action="{{ url_for('preview') }}" method="post">
    <div class="wrap">
        <button>Start Preview</button>
    </div>
</form>
<table class="control">
<form class="form_test_form" action="/enc_config" method="post">
    <h2>_width & _height</h2>
    <input type="text" id="_width" name="_width" class="form-control" placeholder="_width">
    <input type="text" id="_heigth" name="_heigth" class="form-control" placeholder="_heigth" required>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<form id="1_video_fmt" data-script="enc_config">
    <h2>video_format</h2>
    <input type="text" id="_video_fmt" name="_video_fmt" class="form_control" placeholder="_video_fmt">

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<form id="1_img_fmt" data-script="enc_config">
    <h2>image format</h2>
    <input type="text" id="_image_fmt" name="_image_fmt" class="form_control" placeholder="_image_fmt">

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Проблема такова, при нажатии на кнопку "submit" - я получаю ошибку Bad Request и ничего не отправляется.

Comment: А если обернуть весь код enc_config в try-except и в except-блоке вызвать traceback.print_exc() - что в консоль отпечатает?

Comment: @andreymal что куда и тд, можно немного поподробнее.. я немного со всем на ВЫ.

Comment: Пока могу только предложить погуглить исключения и их обработку, ибо времени объяснять всю матчасть у меня в данный момент не имеется. (Для мимопроходящих: BadRequest может выкидывать обращение к request.form, которое я перехватом исключения надеюсь поймать)

Comment: @andreymal ну главная проблема это BadRequest. Как отправить форму не переходя на страницу, уже сделано.

Comment: я нашел в чем проблема, Python не принимает POST запросы, если они не полные; то есть, у меня в скрипте 4 переменные (_width, _heigth и тд), если передать только часть из них, получим - BadRequest.